# Salesforce application | Not able to click on a tab in tabbar using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Need to click on 'Cases' tab in tab bar immediately after login.

Tried below xpath:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Case_Tab']/a")).click()`;

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with xpath == .//*[@id='Case_Tab']/a (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command
>   duration or timeout: 328 milliseconds

Comment: Well then that element doesn't exist. Without any more information like page structure there's nothing anyone can do.

Comment: You can't click something which does not exist. May be your xpath is wrong

Comment: Hey Blustone,please find the below structure<div id="tabContainer" class="brdPalette zen-headerBottom zen-hasTabOrganizer" role="navigation">
<h1 class="zen-assistiveText">Tab Navigation</h1>
<nav>
<ul id="tabBar" class="zen-inlineList zen-tabMenu">
<li id="home_Tab" class="zen-firstItem">
<li id="Chatter_Tab">
<li id="Account_Tab">
<li id="Contact_Tab">
<li id="Case_Tab" class="zen-active brandPrimaryBgr primaryPalette">
<a class="brandPrimaryFgr" href="/500/o" title="Cases Tab - Selected">Cases</a>
<span class="zen-assistiveText">(Currently Selected)</span>
</li>

Comment: No Sujit,I have taken the Xpath from Firepath.Hope that is the correct one only.

Comment: Does it require any mouse hovering before that option to visible and then click?

Comment: No Kapil,Its a visible tab only,Directly we can click on it.

Comment: can you give URL?

Comment: https://test.salesforce.com

Comment: How do i see the option that you are trying to click?

Comment: Sorry Kapil. I cannot share the credential.Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Try putting some wait before and after your click code.

Comment: If you are able to find element using Firebug, then maybe the element is present on a frame.

Answer (score 0):

For applications like Salesforce when you click on links it opens new tabs and each tab has the same 'close Tab' button attribute. So i am guessing you might have more than 1 tab opened and your trying to close a single Tab. Every time you write an xpath you need to check in the browser inspector(preferably Chrome) if unique elements are identified or not. If you have multiple elements matching with the xpath you should modify your xpath to find the unique.

Try below:

i)  `(//li[@id='Case_Tab'])[1]` - Close Tab 1

ii) `(//li[@id='Case_Tab'])[2]` - Close Tab 2

And so on..

Although this is not the most efficient way of locating your element, Should atleast give you more clarity on your problem.